# Can't parse JSON string with greater than sign using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, tags

Here is the JSON:

```
{ "expression" : "Hello World",
  "message" : "Hello<br>World. I'm trying also to write <something> inside greater than and lower than signs."
},
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".info").append(obj[i].message);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="info"></div>
```

What I get is that everything inside "<" and ">" is not shown into the div.

Comment: is it there when you do view source? try a &lt; instead of <

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSON.

The `append` method interprets what you give it as HTML markup if you give it a string. So naturally, `<` characters must be propertly encoded as `&lt;`, just like in HTML generally. Just encode them, and `append` will work correctly.

The sample you gave looks like it is meant to be markup, as you have a `<br>` in it. The problem is the `<something>`, which looks like a tag. It should be `&lt;something>` or `&lt;something&gt;`.

If you wanted the text to be interpreted as text, not HTML, you could use the `text` method, either to replace the `div`'s content entirely:

```
$(".info").text(obj[i].message);
```

...or to append to it as your code is trying to currently:

```
$(".info").append($("<span>").text(obj[i].message).html());
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. I had given up using &lt; because it doesn't work for <something>. Now the <br> is ok. The problem is that I need to show <br> as HTML and <something> as text.

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti: Of course `&lt;` works for `<something>`, just like in HTML (because this **is** HTML). (I'd posted jsbin links here, but jsbin appears to be broken right now.)

Comment: Oh, I saw the links, but can't found the difference between the working and broken examples. T trying to write <something> and &lt;something&gt;, but occurs the same, it is now shown as text. :/

Comment: The difference is exactly what I said it was above: In one of them, the text is `"Hello<br>World. I'm trying also to write <something> inside greater than and lower than signs."` (that's the broken one). In the correct one, it's `"Hello<br>World. I'm trying also to write &lt;something&gt; inside greater than and lower than signs."` Here, I'll post a version using object initializers instead of JSON (since it's the JSON bit that's broken on jsbin right now). Here we are: http://jsbin.com/owocuf/3 ([source](http://jsbin.com/owocuf/3/edit)) I empty the div between to it's clearer.

Comment: Yes, this is working for me. I understood the example. Thanks for the patiente. :-)